# difference between git --git-dir checkout and git checkout

Tags: git-checkout

git checkout acts differently for using option `--git-dir`.

Commands :

1. `inside_gitdir$ git checkout remote/branch`
2. `outside_gitdir$ git --git-dir=/path/.git checkout remote/branch`

Here **command 1** works well and checking out. but the **command 2** shows to move files like :

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
someFiles

Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

I thought both the commands are running in same way. But,

- Why am i getting this error in second command not in first ?
- What is the difference of using `--git-dir` option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.

It seems to work if you do: `git --git-dir=/path/.git --work-tree=/path/ checkout remote/branch`